# How to write a query with mysql where I could have some value compared to multiple values with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've been coding all night so if this question makes no sense I apologize.  It's been a while since I've had to write out a query but I thought there was a way where I could do something like...

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call 
WHERE upload_id = (SELECT uploadId FROM userUploads where user_id = us.id)  
   and callDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND now() AND click = 1) AS weeklyCalls,
```

My question is how would I check the upload_id to multiple ids within the same query.  I feel like I should be able to compare it to the sub query running.

Everything I'm referring to in the example query is taking place on the second line.

Comment: Why don't you use a standard inner join?

Comment: I'm using joins for everything else but since this is part of the select I'm not sure that a join would actually work here.

Comment: How about `... from call c inner join userUploads uu on c.upload_id = uu.upload_id and us.id = uu.user_id where ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use IN instead of "="

```
WHERE upload_id IN (SELECT uploadId FROM...)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  In my head I kept thing it was any.  Thanks Miroshko